# How to navigate divs in a custom built single page app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm not sure how JS frameworks work as far as single page app functionality. I've got a pseudo single page app, with no framework. I have 3 tabs that will toggle visibility for 3 different hidden div's on the same page.

So far I've been able to hide two and display one on click to allow the page to "navigate" without changing pages. I'm running into some complications, however, because I'd like to run some ajax calls to keep the data on my div's updated when visible. I'd also like to be able to pass which page I want visible in the URL for links, etc.

Basically I'm wondering what the best way is to identify what "screen" is visible, so I know what ajax calls to make, but I'd prefer if I didn't have to check the css on the element for visibility for these types of things. Can this be done with anchor href's in the url? I could use URL variables, but again I don't want to reload the page, and I could probably make a JS variable to look at and change as I click my tabs, but I wouldn't really be able to pass this in the url.

Here is some code. The app is for a dice game, to add some context. The three tabs are simple empty divs with background images that sit on the left hand side of my screen for nav.

```
$('#chatTab').click(animateChat);
$('#timelineTab').click(animateTimeline);
$('#rollTab').click(animateTheTable);

//opens and closes chat box
function animateChat () {
    $('#stats').fadeOut('slow', function(){$('#chat').delay(800).fadeIn('slow');});
    $('#theTable').fadeOut('slow', function(){$('#chat').delay(800).fadeIn('slow');});
}

//opens and closes timeline box
function animateTimeline () {
    $('#chat').fadeOut('slow', function(){$('#stats').delay(800).fadeIn('slow');});
    $('#theTable').fadeOut('slow', function(){$('#stats').delay(800).fadeIn('slow');});
}

//opens and closes the roll table
function animateTheTable(){
    $('#stats').fadeOut('slow', function(){$('#theTable').delay(800).fadeIn('slow');});
    $('#chat').fadeOut('slow', function(){$('#theTable').delay(800).fadeIn('slow');});
}
```

Comment: Can you post your relevant coding?

Comment: Yes, this can be done with the anchor. You can also use classes, something like checking which div has `.active` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very open ended question so the answer depends on how far you want the app to go.

If your page will only ever have a few UI elements and only one layer of navigation, you are probably better off doing it with straight Jquery and avoiding extra complication.

Jquery can handle URL tracking by getting window.location on page load and performing your animations above. Read about handling URLs with JavaScript here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

But keep in mind that this only works in modern browsers. Old versions will not handle dynamic URL changes well.

To save having to set up all the logic to check the URL you could use a location framework like [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) or Jquery Address.

If you intend the game to become very complex with multiple screens and some kind of database, go with Angular Back or another JS framework. This will handle all your routing and animations, including URL tracking plus heaps of other features you may or may not need down the track. The learning curve is steep but once you are there you can make ANYTHING.

Be careful though, it's easy to jump in headfirst and use the whizz-bang frameworks and ending up spending weeks doing something you could have barreled out in a few days with straight JS, CSS and HTML. Complexity kills completion.

Comment: Forgot to mention one of my favourite little sites for finding specific plugins for performing takss in JS-

http://microjs.com/#URL